# dragenter and dragleave event listener D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, addeventlistener

I would like to change the color of tiles in a grid as they are being 'dragged over'. The grid is created using d3 and svg. I have tried several different methods, but have had little success.
Here is my code as of my latest attempt:

```
var w = 960,
h = 520,
z = 40,
x = w / z,
y = h / z;

var svg = d3.select("#grid").append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);

var grid = d3.range(y).map(function(dy) {
  return d3.range(x).map(function(dx) {
  return {x: dx, y: dy};
  });
});



var g = svg.selectAll("g")
    .data(grid)
  .enter().append("g")                 // Group each row's rects in a g
    .selectAll("rect")                 // Do a nested selection
    .data(function(d) { return d; })   // Bind the sub-array for this row
      .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("width", z)
      .attr("height", z)
      .attr("start", false)
      .attr("clicked", false)
      .attr("previous", null)
      .attr('x', function(d) { return d.x * z; })
      .attr('y', function(d) { return d.y * z; })

      .on("dragover", draggedOver)
      .style("stroke", "rgb(6,120,155)")
      .style("stroke-width", 2)
      .style("fill", "rgb(255, 255, 255)");

function draggedOver(){
d3.select(this).transition().style("fill","green");
}
```

The focus is on the "on('dragover')" event. Thanks in advance

Comment: I make a fiddle of your code http://jsfiddle.net/3Rk5N/308/ , and you can already change color of tiles.
Maybe I misunderstood the gol

Comment: Thanks for having a look, Yeah it seems to half work. It doesn't drag smoothly and is inconsistent, so I thought there might be a better method

Comment: I don't understand your code.  Nothing is draggable to fire the `dragover` event.  Add a `draggable` and it works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/3Rk5N/315/